# JPA @Version merge Behavior not working for EclipseLink

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

When I deploy a simple project to a WildFly 9.0.1 Server, which uses hibernate by default, everything works as demonstrated.  However, deploying to a Glassfish 4.1 (or Payara) server, which uses EclipseLink by default, causes my integration tests to fail.

Specifically, the EntityManager.merge method causes the version to change from 0 to 1 when an insert is required while deployed on Glassfish, but not WildFly.

My Integration Tests are calling the JAX-RS Service for each test piece.  Each method in the ToDoManager is a JPA Transaction so if I am not mistaken, I do not need to flush for the DB to be updated.

**JAX-RS ExceptionMapper  to Catch EJBExeption:**

```
@Provider
public class EJBExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<EJBException> {

@Override
public Response toResponse(EJBException ex) {
    Throwable cause = ex.getCause();
    Response unknownError = Response.serverError().
            header("cause", ex.toString()).build();
    if (cause == null) {
        return unknownError;
    }

    if (cause instanceof OptimisticLockException) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.CONFLICT).
                header("cause", "conflict occured: " + cause).
                build();
    }

    return unknownError;
}
```

}

**The Save Endpoint for Create and Update Requests:**

```
@Stateless
@Path("todos")
public class TodosResource {

    @Inject
    ToDoManager manager;

    ... other REST Calls ...

    @POST
    public Response save(@Valid ToDo todo, @Context UriInfo info) {
        ToDo saved = this.manager.save(todo);
        long id = saved.getId();
        URI uri = info.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path("/"+id).build();
        return Response.created(uri).build();
    }
}
```

**The underlying persistence:**

```
@Stateless
@Interceptors(BoundaryLogger.class)
public class ToDoManager {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    ... other persistence methods ...

    public ToDo save(ToDo todo) {
        return this.em.merge(todo);
    }
}
```

This following test will throw an OptimisticLockException when deployed on Glassfish for the **first** update attempt and the test fails when it should pass. Whereas when deployed to WildFly, the first update occurs, the test passes, and then the second test passes because I am checking for the 409 status code.

**The Tests:**

```
@Test
public void crud() {
    // build a JSON ToDo
    JsonObjectBuilder todoBuilder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
    JsonObject todoToCreate = todoBuilder.
            add("caption", "implement").
            add("priority", 10).
            build();

    // Run Create Test
    Response postResponse = this.provider.target().request().
            post(Entity.json(todoToCreate));
    assertThat(postResponse.getStatus(), is(201));
    String location = postResponse.getHeaderString("Location");
    System.out.println("location = " + location);

    // Run Find Test
    JsonObject dedicatedTodo = this.provider.client().
            target(location).
            request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
            get(JsonObject.class);
    assertTrue(dedicatedTodo.getString("caption").contains("implement"));

    // Run Update Test
    JsonObjectBuilder updateBuilder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
    JsonObject updated = updateBuilder.
            add("id", dedicatedTodo.getInt("id")).
            add("caption", "implemented").
            add("priority", 10).
            add("version", dedicatedTodo.getInt("version")).
            build();

    Response updateResponse = this.provider.client().
            target(location).
            request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
            put(Entity.json(updated));
    assertThat(updateResponse.getStatus(), is(200));

    // Run Update Test Again for Lock Testing
    updateBuilder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
    updated = updateBuilder.
            add("id", dedicatedTodo.getInt("id")).
            add("caption", "implemented").
            add("priority", 8).
            add("version", dedicatedTodo.getInt("version")).
            build();

    updateResponse = this.provider.client().
            target(location).
            request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
            put(Entity.json(updated));
    assertThat(updateResponse.getStatus(), is(409));
    String conflictInformation = updateResponse.getHeaderString("cause");
    assertNotNull(conflictInformation);
    System.out.println("conflictInformation = " + conflictInformation);
```

When I look at the `@Version private long version` value after a create on Glassfish, the value is 1 causing the first update to fail. However, on WildFly, it remains a 0 thus allowing the first update to occur.

Since I already have a production Payara Server up and running, and I would like to use this methodology on a future project, any help in explaining how I might get this to work on Glassfish would be very helpful.

Comment: Do you happen to use the JPA same provider with the same version on both the servers? Otherwise, the behaviour you observed could be a provider specific behaviour (thus, not container specific). GlassFish and WildFly ship EclipseLink and Hibernate as the default JPA implementations respectively.

Comment: Right you are!  WildFly is using hibernate and Glassfish is using EclipseLink. so I will try using Hibernate on Glassfish to see if I can make that work.  Thank you!

Comment: Adding hibernate 5.4.0 as the default provider for Payara and Glassfish did not resolve the issue.  I will keep digging, but it does not seem to be container or JPA implementation Specific.  I noticed during the Workshop, Adam Bien uses WildFly and Payara interchangeably. Thank you for any other possible insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should have been obvious, however, I was following a workshop and the workshop did not include the following.

The update calls during the test required the ID and Version of the object being edited.  Once I added this information, the first update succeeds and the second update fails with the expected OptimisticLockException thus passing the test.

Answer (score 1):

There's not really enough code to work out what's going on. This will depend on the transaction boundaries and/or when you flush to the database. I can't work out from the code what the transaction boundaries are.  The Version field should be incremented when the object is written to the database either by an explicit flush or by a transaction commit.

In your save method you could try an do an em.flush to see if the behaviour is then consistent between the two providers.

You can ensure you have a consistent starting value by doing something like;

```
@Version 
private int version = 1;
```

Comment: I have edited the post to provide more code.  The Class is stateless so the  `return this.em.merge(todo);` method should already be a JPA Transaction.  While troubleshooting I did set the `@Version private long version = 0;` but it made no difference.  the issue still occurred.

Comment: Try with 1 as the initial value or pass in an initial value of 1 when building the JSON object.

Comment: I tried both as an initial value on the Entity and when building the JSON object just now.  the Create Method fails on Glassfish and Payara but with a 500 Response Code instead of the 409.

Comment: Still no answer to this question.  I have dug deeper, and it appears to be an EclipseLink issue, but no matter how I try to use the @Version I cannot update a record without getting an OptimisiticLockException. Any help would be appreciated.